# Creating "abnormal" 3D polygons in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl

I am currently re-creating the following in openGL. [Shift Pale Lager Logo](http://www.newbelgium.com/Images/Shiftcircle.jpg).

Earlier I accomplished in creating the outer portions of the gears shown below.

[image]

Now, the next thing I am trying to tackle is creating the inner portions of the gears. Because the gears are 3D I can't take the naive approach (creating custom 2D polygons), and every approach I can come up with just seems inefficient and not very practical. It's almost like I just want to create flat polygons, then give them a depth, but I don't know how to go at it.

Comment: Have you thought about using a modelling tool like Blender?

Comment: This is a class project I am working on where everything is done in openGL. Hence why I am trying to do it the hard way.

Comment: I don't understand what "Because the gears are 3D I can't take the naive approach and create custom polygons and rotate them" is supposed to mean. But if you're asking how to rotate groups of vertices, then maybe you should read up on transformations here: https://open.gl/transformations

Comment: Sorry, Ill make an edit and try to make that more clear. I have no problem rotating the points in unison. All the gears here have a depth, which means that their interiors will need a depth as well. And I am unsure on how to create the abnormal shapes in 3D. Building them in 2D is easy enough, but not what I need here.

Comment: @SeanCallahan well even if "everything is done in openGL" when you have more complex shapes and no reasonable way of defining them parametrically, then typing in the points into your text-editor is just inefficient. Just model them in a 3D editor, you can always just get a list of the points after you have done that and paste them into a header if you don't want to load the points from an external file.

Comment: Oh and the "just give it depth" thing is usually called "extrude" in those 3D editors